# How do I determine whether my services are using runit or init?

Tags: ubuntu, init-script

How do I determine whether my services are using `runit` or `init`? I use Ubuntu 10.0.4.

Such as nginx, chef, puppet, etc.

Answer (score 1):

[`pstree`](http://www.linfo.org/pstree.html)  gives me processes as below,

```
$ pstree
init-+-VBoxService---7*[{VBoxService}]                                                                 
     |-acpid                                                                                           
     |-atd                                                                                             
     |-cron                                                                                            
     |-dbus-daemon                                                                                     
     |-2*[dhclient3]                                                                                   
     |-5*[getty]                                                                                       
     |-login---bash---sudo---su---bash---pstree                                                        
     |-nginx---4*[nginx]                                                                               
     |-rsyslogd---3*[{rsyslogd}]                                                                       
     |-runsvdir-+-runsv---node---{node}                                                                
     |          |-runsv---java---9*[{java}]                                                            
     |          `-runsv                                                                                
     |-sshd                                                                                            
     |-udevd---2*[udevd]                                                                               
     |-upstart-socket-                                                                                 
     |-upstart-udev-br                                                                                 
     `-whoopsie---{whoopsie}
```

With this, I think, it can be decided.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure, but since [`runit`](http://smarden.org/runit/) uses a supervisor, you should be able to recognize it from looking at the process tree, i.e. from the output of `ps faux` or, if it's installed, `pstree`.

You could also just *ask `runit`*, i.e. run `sv status nginx`.

Note however that if all you did was *install `runit`*, possibly nothing got *switched to use it* instead of "plain" `init`.  You can examine `/proc/cmdline` for an occurrence of `init=/sbin/runit-init`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need your **services to have a common control interface**, it may be better to mimic init.d script behavior with `sv` command. If `sv` is called as a `/etc/init.d/NAME command`, it automatically translates this to `sv command NAME`.

If you run some service (let's say ssh) under `runit` supervisor, you can do the following:

1. Rename current init script:

   ```
   dpkg-divert --rename /etc/init.d/ssh
   ```
2. Create symlink with the same name:

   ```
   ln -vs $(which sv) /etc/init.d/ssh
   ```

Now you can manage your service with familiar commands like this:

```
/etc/inti.d/ssh status
invoke-rc.d ssh status
```

Having symlink will cause some complaints about LSB-headers, though. So it's even better not to have symlink, but to create a wrapper script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# copy these headers from your original script which
    # can be found at /etc/init.d/ssh.distrib
    ### END INIT INFO

exec /usr/bin/chpst -b $0 /usr/bin/sv "$@"
```

This way you can manage services the same way, whether they're being under `runit` or not.